# Node ( Express ) file import into controllers

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6

In my express application I have a `methods` directory containing `methods.js` file where I am writing very common functions I need to use in every controllers.

methods.js

```
function helloworld() {
    return "Hello World"
}
```

now I need to add the file into my controller file and I need to use the function..

I have tried

```
const Methods = require('../methods/methods')

exports.passengerStatus = (req, res) => {
    let x = Methods.helloworld()
    console.log(x)
}
```

the route is being called but error is

```
 Methods.helloworld() is not define
```

How can I import the file into controller? And is there any way to import the file, so that I can access the file methods without importing in controllers.

Answer (score 1):

You can write methods.js as below

```
var commonFunctions = {};

commonFunctions.sample = function(){
   // Write your code here
};

// Add other functions as sample here


module.exports = commonFunctions;
```

Comment: cool. is there any way to import the file globally. so that I can access the functions without importing the file ?

Comment: Currently there is no way to import file globally.

Answer (score 0):

you can also write this way

**method.js**

```
  function helloWorld() {

    return "hello method";
}

function mySecondMethod() {

    return "hello my second method";
}

function myThirdMethod() {

    return "hello my third method";
}

module.exports = {
    helloWorld,
    mySecondMethod,
    myThirdMethod
}
```

**constroller.js**

```
 let { helloWorld,mySecondMethod,myThirdMethod } = require("./method.js");
console.log(helloWorld);
console.log(mySecondMethod);
console.log(myThirdMethod);
```

Comment: I have hundreds of function in the file. should I export all function as you given ?

Comment: yeah that may be possible.Please have a look updated code.